# Facebook Action Type Get Code button not working

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, action, facebook-fql, facebook-opengraph

Is anybody else having a problem with the Get Code button for Facebook Action Type?  In all the browsers I have tried it just flashes up an empty Loading box, and then disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue but solved it. You have to create a story first (Open Graph -> Stories).
Combining your Action and Object, after saving that you can do "Get Code" on your action.